# pass parameter to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Requests}" var="request">
    <tr>
        <td>{!request.Subject}</td>
        <td>{!request.Type}</td>
        <td>{!request.Location__r.Name}</td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}" >
                <apex:param value="{!request.CreatedDate}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

On click of request.subject I need to pass variable (Subject) to controller.how to achieve I this.I don't want to use commandlink and param to pass parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `apex:actionFunction`

Controller

```
public String mySubject {get;set;}

public PageReference myMethod(){
    System.debug('mySubject: ' + mySubject);
}
```

Page

```
<apex:actionFunction name="send"
                     action="{!myMethod}"
                     reRender="none">
    <apex:param name="p1" assignto="{!mySubject}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:repeat value="{!Requests}" var="request">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="send('{!request.Subject}')">{!request.Subject}</a></td>
        <td>{!request.Type}</td>
        <td>{!request.Location__r.Name}</td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}" >
                <apex:param value="{!request.CreatedDate}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using the actionSupport tag. See [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_actionSupport.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) for the docs.

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!Requests}" var="request">
        <tr>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{!request.Subject}">
             <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" >
               <apex:param name="p1" assignto="{!mySubject}" value="{!request.Subject}"/>
             </apex:actionSupport>
            </apex:outputText></td>
            <td>{!request.Type}</td>
            <td>{!request.Location__r.Name}</td>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}" >
                    <apex:param value="{!request.CreatedDate}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
```

note: This has been hacked in the browser so there maybe some typos...